# Make http request over array every minute

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous

I have to retrive lat e lon over 1000 ip addresses. Since I have to use ip-api.com /batch, the post method to this api require max 100 Json paramenter length EVERY MINUTE. I take in input the array over 1000 ip addresses and I made a new  array with each index another array of length max 100. Now i'm struggling make http call for each index over array and wait one minute for a new request over the next index.

```
  //for example I have two index in groups and each index has other 3 
    indexes 
   let groups= [[ { query: '193.206.170.145', fields: 'lat,lon' },
      { query: '37.186.207.50', fields: 'lat,lon' },
     { query: '193.206.170.144', fields: 'lat,lon' },
      { query: '62.18.244.163', fields: 'lat,lon' }],
      [ { query: '79.52.35.144', fields: 'lat,lon' },
         { query: '62.18.249.56', fields: 'lat,lon' },
       { query: '176.200.132.147', fields: 'lat,lon' }]]


groups.forEach( el => makeRequest(el));


function makeRequest (array){
let toJson = JSON.stringify(array)
  setInterval(function(){
  axios.post('http://ip-api.com/batch',toJson)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
 })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
     });

  },60000);
}

 Expected:

  [{ lat: 45.8, lon: 8.8333 },
   { lat: 45.8155, lon: 8.82753 },
   { lat: 45.8, lon: 8.8333 }]

 after one minute   
   [{ lat: 41.818, lon: 12.4148 },
   { lat: 45.4643, lon: 9.1895 },
   { lat: 45.5324, lon: 9.0402 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const axios = require('axios');

let groups = [[{ query: '193.206.170.145', fields: 'lat,lon' },
{ query: '37.186.207.50', fields: 'lat,lon' },
{ query: '193.206.170.144', fields: 'lat,lon' },
{ query: '62.18.244.163', fields: 'lat,lon' }],
[{ query: '79.52.35.144', fields: 'lat,lon' },
{ query: '62.18.249.56', fields: 'lat,lon' },
{ query: '176.200.132.147', fields: 'lat,lon' }]]

groups.forEach(el => makeRequest(el));

function makeRequest(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            let toJson = JSON.stringify(array)
            setTimeout(function () {
                axios.post('http://ip-api.com/batch', toJson)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }, 60000 * i);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This one make all http request after one minute. I would like , to make request one the first index and after the response , wait one minute and then make the http request over second index

Comment: No, it does not. If you look closer at it you will see that the timeout is a function of the loop counter value. So every consecutive request is 60000ms apart from the previous one.

Comment: it doesn't work . The http request is a post make on each element of groups. You make http request for each element inside each index of groups